# How to reverse sort number with only count

Tags: java, android

Sorry for the noobish question, i've been trying to figure it out to no avail.

I'm making an Android application which has a list view. I wish to have each row in the have its corresponding row count next to it but in reverse order.

The thing I seem to have trouble with is reversing the numbers with only 1 number and its maximum number.

Example:

I pull things out of my database in reverse order.

So this is how things look on the list view: Row count | Name

0 - John
1 - Jez
2 - Jen

When I add a value to the list view, it becomes

0 - NewName
1- John
2 - Jez
3 - Jen

What I really want is the reverse order... so Jen being 1 and Jez 2, John 3 and any new additions added on, but I'm not sure how to do it as the only thing I have is the row count and the number of rows.

Is there a formula which can do this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Solved by Loki and Richard - DOH, Max number - number.

Comment: Maximum number - number

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard. I tried doing this, but when the number is below the max number / 2 then the values won't work. *Actually i think you might be right - retrying it now. DOH. Edit: I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not added any code, but generally you could do something like this:

```
int id = (maxRows - rowIndex);
```

Then just add that to the list view text with something like:

```
setText(person + " " + String.valueOf(id));
```

It may not be exactly what you want, but without code, we're running a bit blind. Should point you in the right direction though.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! Richard and you are correct. I feel like an idiot now. but thanks! I really appreciate it.